# Multiplayer queue system for matchmaking

Tags: multiplayer

I'm building an mp game that needs to have some sort of a queue system (eg League of Legends, CSGO, Dota2...)

So my question is how to implement such ?

I mean the core concept (I'm not looking for done code, even though some code would be welcome)

EDIT:

I have created a lobby system where you can invite players and if they accept their id is put into the lobby array and the lobby id is returned to them on client side. So the problem now is when the lobby creator hits the start queue button... How to find other lobbies that combine 8 players (2 teams of 4) but leaves the premade players in the same team

Comment: You already know which players belong to the same team because they are in the same lobby-array. I don't understand the problem you're having. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @1000ml Yes but I need 2 teams of 4 players. Lets say 3 premades queue up, how are they gonna find the fourth player for their team